# HBase Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool

Tags: hadoop, hbase

**EDIT: Problem sovled (see comment for explnation)**

I installed HBase. When I'm trying to start "**start-hbase.sh**", I get some errors:

> **Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool**
>
> **Error: Could not find or**
>   **load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKServerTool**

My installation directory is: `C:\Users\Alon\Downloads\hadoop_temp\hbase-2.2.4`

And I configured HBASE_HOME to: `C:\Users\Alon\Downloads\hadoop_temp\hbase-2.2.4`

And also HBASE_CONF_DIR:  `C:\Users\Alon\Downloads\hadoop_temp\hbase-2.2.4\conf`

In addition, I added `C:\Users\Alon\Downloads\hadoop_temp\hbase-2.2.4\bin` to the environment var Path.

JAVA_HOME=`C:\Users\Alon\Downloads\jdk1.8.0_202` (as an environment variable and also in `hbase-env.sh`)

I would like to get your help please, since I don't know how to solve the problem.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you update the `JAVA_HOME` variable in `hbase-env.sh` ? Also change the value of `HBASE_HOME` to `C:\Users\Alon\Downloads\hadoop_temp\hbase-2.2.4\`.

Comment: @franklinsijo Problem solved! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `CLASSPATH` is not picking up the libraries under `$HBASE_HOME/lib`.

Set the value of `HBASE_HOME` to the Hbase installation directory and Update the `hbase-env.sh` with `JAVA_HOME` variable.

Restart Hbase `start-hbase.sh`.